# Grub Rescue: No Such partition (Havn't found answer on other questions)

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a pc that I have. So the first time I tried to install it, I had Ubuntu installed as well. I just recklessly installed Windows (not doing a clean installation).Now whenever I turn on the pc, and I get: Unknown filesystem , No such partition, Grub Rescue:

Even after using bootrec commands in the command prompt of windows 10 installation doesn't work. I have also tried installing Ubuntu. When that has to reboot, it takes me back to the grub rescue again. The only time Grub rescue doesn't happen is when I go to the BIOS or to the boot drive menu. Thanks!

file:///home/ubuntu/Desktop/bootinfo.html - is the boot info

Comment: Have you mixed UEFI & BIOS installs? And then settings in UEFI/BIOS on which way you are booting? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: `file:///home/ubuntu/Desktop/bootinfo.html` is the summary report on your computer which the rest of us can't see. You need to run `boot-repair` and post the results to the Internet such that we can see them. You'll have the option of creating the summary report in `pastebin.com` with a warning that machine details will be reported. You need to accept the warning to generate the report to the Internet. Also make sure you follow the recommended repair steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think this answer may help many people who are facing the same exact problem. Just go the Ubuntu installation, and instead of custom partitions, just press clear hard drive and let ubuntu install. Grub didn't stop me now. Now I properly installed WIndows, and I am typing this on the pc with the grub problem!